# Spiceworks SQL Monitor cant authenticate

Tags: sql, performance-monitoring, monitoring

I have SpiceWorks 4.7, installed and added the sql monitor extension to monitor our SQL servers. It does identify our sql servers correctly, but when I put the login information in it can't authenticate, with the following error message.

```
Authentication failed. Check the login and password, and ensure that the server is configured for remote connections.
```

I get the same result trying to use windows authentication.

WE do use an alternate port# could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this two things:

1. Make sure to enable [allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277) on the target server.
2. Make sure the firewall is opened to allow connections through your new port.
3. Try to login using `YourServerName,1433` as user name instead of only using `YourServerName`. (don't forget to change the port number 1433 with your port number.)

Also make sure mixed mode authentication is on and TCP\IP is enabled on the target server.
Good Luck

Comment: Hey Dani, I would gladly do that but I don't know how to do it with the extention that is in spiceworks. It seems that they default it to the standard port. The only thing I can change through the front end is the username and password, not the machine/instance name. unless there is a config file somewhere I don't see how I can do this.